# Windows CE 7.0 application unable to debbug in steps

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, motorola

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 for development for Motorola WR41N0, which has Windows CE 7.0 operating system. As program was initially used on Windows CE 5.0, I just changed settings to fit to new operating system. Everything is going ok, except debugging. I am able to set breakpoint and it stops on it, but I am unable to make steps (F10 key). I made a build for older device Motorola WT4090 with Windows CE 5.0 and it was running ok and I was also able to debug in steps. Then I switched devices and it deployed older version on new device. Its graphical interface didn't start, but I was able to debug start routine in steps. After rebuild and redeploy I wasn't able to debug in steps again. Please give me some advice what to do, thank you.

Comment: What happens when u go to next step (step into)??

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing using C/C++ you may need to install those patches on your VS machine:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11935
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2483802
(should be the same fix, but it's not easy to understand this on MSDN...)